# Android MediaPlayer cannot read SDCARD?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I wrote an Android app several years ago (using Eclipse and ADT). Recently, I had to go back to it using **Android Studio** because it mysteriously stopped working.

I've traced the problem to `MediaPlayer`. It can no longer create a `MediaPlayer` if it's trying to access external storage (**sdcard0**). The Android permissions that worked years ago should still work today, so I don't know what the issue is.

My app copies audio files from the Internet and places them in external storage. This proves **sdcard0** is working fine.

The offending code is:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.somename.myapp/files/beach.mp3");
```

This gives me a `NullPointerException`.

If I copy this audio file into my resources and do this:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beach);
```

it works fine.

Nothing wrong with my device. The problem exhibits on another device, too.

So what the devil is going on???

Comment: Try to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of hardcoded value.

Comment: Indeed, do not assume what the path of the storage device will be, and beware that it appears different to ADB than it will to an app.   Installing a working file manager app would be a good way to verify things, but don't simply copy the path where a file manager finds it *on a given device* into your code, as that will not be portable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> In some Android applications, we may download the mp3 file from
>   internet and save them in SD Card. In this case, we will find and play
>   the audio file by URI. If you want to create an Android music player
>   app, this will be the proper way to handle your music.

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/path/to/your/example.mp3");
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but as in the comment above do not assume what the path of the storage device will be, but rather determine it at runtime.

Comment: I read your comment above. The path to the file in the example that I put was just to exemplify and you should check this in your app.